# Does optgroup not work in IE 10 correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, internet-explorer

So my question at hand is this: does optgroup not work in IE?

The current Plnkr works in Chrome but not in IE 10 and I'm trying to figure out how to make this work across both browsers. Is this a known issue? I can expand/ collapse the groups in chrome but I cannot do so in IE 10. Is there any kind of work around to this?

[Outgroup Expand/ Collapse Selection](http://plnkr.co/edit/gfDhMYHhrbyTWQzrUw5l?p=preview)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.1" data-semver="1.4.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">


  <select multiple class="box">
    <optgroup ng-click="clickOptGroup(key);" ng-repeat="(key,value) in data" label="{{value.label}}">
      <option ng-mousedown="mouseDown()" ng-mouseup="mouseUp()" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();" ng-show="value.expanded" ng-repeat="id in value.ids">{{id}}</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: yeah it is, I took it from the previous question because I have a new one, I'm trying to understand this optgroup functionality and this has been a huge pain in the butt

Comment: `select`, and by proxy `option` and `optgroup`, elements are notoriously fickle in IE. If you need to dynamically show/hide them I'd strongly suggest you use a library which converts the contents to elements which are more cross-browser friendly for UI manipulation, such as Select2

Comment: I had a feeling this was it, but google was only supplying so much. I hate IE so much lol

Comment: We all hate it. Maybe this in one reason because Chris Wilson moved to google while IE9 was in development. He also hate his work =) - https://www.linkedin.com/in/cwilso/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer version 10 still does not support any useful events on optgroup or option. The MSDN documentation says that optgroup supports click events. But IE 10 that still does not seem to supporting it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535876(v=vs.85).aspx

**Answer: No way in IE10**

But you could make it work by for other browsers using this workarround:

```
$scope.data = [{
    label: "My Label", ids: [ "one id", "another id" ], 
    expanded: navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 10") !== -1 ? true : true
},{ 
    label: "My Other Label", ids: [ "one id", "another id" ], 
    expanded: navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 10") !== -1 ? false : true
}];
```

Comment: IE is so depressing -_-

Comment: the first expanded is always true